# Merging conditional probability

Tags: probability

If I have `P(A|C)` and `P(B|C)`, is there an easy way to find `P(A,B|C)`?

I am trying to prove that A and B are independent, but I only have information regarding `P(A|C) for all C`, `P(B|C) for all C`, and `P(C) for all C`.

Comment: Specify "for all $C$". Because if that were really "all", then you could easily reconstruct $A, B$ and thus $A\cap B$ etc...

Comment: What if $(A,B)$ is independent from $C$?

Comment: I can get P(A) and P(B), but the probability values are all dummy placeholders (e.g. $P(A|C_i) = f_i(x_i)$, so there is really no way to see what's P(A,B) from P(A) and P(B)

Comment: @D.Thomine is it possible for A to be dependent from C but A,B to be independent from C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this equation?

$ P(A \cap B | C) = P(A | B \cap C) P(B | C) $

It is one way to merge two conditional probability. You can easily prove this equation by only using the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Does this apply to conjunction? e.g. $P(A \cap B | C) = P(A | B \cap C)P(B | C)$?

Comment: Oops... You are right. I corrected.

Comment: This helped, thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to know how this applies to using chain rule? e.g. $P(A \cap B \cap C | D)$?